# Ubuntu Server 22.04 ping timeout even though it gets IP address and it shows connected on my router

Tags: networking, command-line, server, 22.04

Ubuntu Server 22.04 ping times out even though it gets the IP address and it shows it's connected on my router. The timeout happens when I ping to/from it in the network, but running `ip a` shows that eno1 has an IP address.

This problem happened suddenly for no apparent reason.
I tried changing the cable, but it didn't work.

Here is the output of what you requested. They are all images because I can't SSH to the server:

Results of `ip a`:

[image: ip a output]

Results of `resolvectl`:

[image: resolvectl output]

Results of `ls -l resolve.conf`:

[image: ls -l resolve.conf output]

I discovered the reason for this. It happens when I try to download torrents on qbittorrent Hotio container, but stopping the container and restarting doesn't solve the problem that's why that when it happened the firsy time I thought that wasn't the reason. How can I get my connection back immediately after this happens? Rebooting doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have a route ? `ip route;ip link`. Read `man ip ip-route  ip-link`.

Comment: Please update question with output of `ip a` and `resolvectl status` and `ls -l /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: I don't know what happened but the server is now working after a power outage,
It is like this these couple days power here is not stable because of the weather and 
load on the local power grid.